# Distributed Substring counts

Tags: java, string, algorithm, hadoop

I'm new to Hadoop, I'm trying to implement an algorithm that simply counts the occourrences of the substring of length `x`. It's long but simple.

Here's a pratical example with input: `"ABCABCAGD" x=4, m=2`

**MAP**

1. Extraction of the substrings of length `x` (what we call x-string):

   ```
   ABCA,BCAB,CABC,ABCA,BCAG,CAGD`
   ```
2. For each x-string I extract its "signature", defined as the lexicographic minor substring of length `m`:

   ```
   AB, AB, AB, AB, AG, AG
   ```
3. Now for each "signature" I generate another string as follows:
   I concatenate x-strings with same signature AND contiguous.
   In the example there are 2 signature `AB`, `CB`. The x-string belongs to both signature are contigous, so the output of my Map task is:

   ```
   Key=AB; Value=ABCABCA
   Key=AG; Value=BCAGD
   ```

   (as you can see for 2  contigous x-strings I append just the last character, the fist value is the result of `ABCA + B + C + A`)

**Combiner**

4. Now again I extract the x-strings out of my map output and my combiner output is:

   ```
   Key=ABCA,Value=1
   Key=BCAB,Value=1
   Key=CABC,Value=1
   Key=ABCA,Value=1
   ```

   (belongs to the fist map output -> `Key=AB; Value=ABCABCA`)

   ```
   Key=BCAG,Value=1
   Key=CAGD,Value=1
   ```

   (belongs to the second map output -> `Key=AG; Value=BCAGD`)

**Reducer**

5. Now I should simply count the occurrences of each x-string (yeah the algorithm simply do that)

   And this should be the Reduce output:

   ```
   ABCA:2
   BCAB:1
   CABC:1
   BCAG:1
   CAGD:1
   ```

   The **problem** is the output is:

   ```
   ABCA:1
   ABCA:1
   BCAB:1
   CABC:1
   BCAG:1
   CAGD:1
   ```

---

My reducer currently is very similar to WordCount, it simply iterates and sums the values.
I'm pretty sure the Reduce Task (I set the MR Job with `setNumReduceTasks(1)`) somehow gives the wrong output because it doesn't have all the data together.

What do you think about this structure?

I choose to do the x-strings extraction in the Combiner step, is this the right place for that or is it part of the problem I have?

---

**PLEASE NOTE** : as I consequence of my algorithm, the Combiner have more output record than inputs..can this be a problem?

**THE CODE** (simplified from non-hadoop logic)

```
public class StringReader extends Mapper<NullWritable, RecordInterface, LongWritable, BytesWritable> {
    public void map(NullWritable key, RecordInterface value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            HadoopRun.util.extractSuperKmersNew(value.getValue().getBytes(), context);
    }
}



public void extractSuperKmersNew(byte[] r1, Mapper<NullWritable, RecordInterface, LongWritable, BytesWritable>.Context context) {

....
    context.write(new LongWritable(current_signature),new BytesWritable(super_kmer));
....
}


public class Combiner extends Reducer<LongWritable, BytesWritable, LongWritable, BytesWritable> {

    protected void reduce(LongWritable arg0, Iterable<BytesWritable> arg1,
            Reducer<LongWritable, BytesWritable, LongWritable, BytesWritable>.Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        for (BytesWritable val : arg1) {
            extractKmers(val.get(), context)            

        }
    }
}


public void extractKmers(byte[] superkmer, Reducer<LongWritable, BytesWritable, LongWritable, BytesWritable>.Context arg2) {    


int end = superkmer.length - k + 1;

//Extraction of k-string from the aggregated strings
for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
    long l = byteArrayToLong(superkmer, i);
    try {
    // quickfix to send to reducer Key = K-string, Value=1
    byte[] ONE = new byte[1];
    ONE[0] = 1;
        arg2.write(new LongWritable(l), new BytesWritable(ONE));
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {

    }
}
}



public class CounterReducer extends Reducer<LongWritable, BytesWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    protected void reduce(LongWritable kmer, Iterable<BytesWritable> count,
            Reducer<LongWritable, BytesWritable, Text, IntWritable>.Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

 int sum=0;
 for (BytesWritable val : count) {
        sum +=1
      }
      context.write(new Text(LongWritableToText(key), new IntWritable(sum));

    }
}


public class HadoopRun extends Configured implements Tool {

    public static Utility util;

    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        /* HADOOP START */
        Configuration conf = this.getConf();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Mapping Strings");
        job.setJarByClass(HadoopRun.class);
        job.setMapperClass(StringReader.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(Combiner.class);
        job.setReducerClass(CounterReducer.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(BytesWritable.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class); 
        job.setPartitionerClass(KPartitioner.class); 


        job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
        job.setInputFormatClass(FASTAShortInputFileFormat.class);
        FASTAShortInputFileFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(conf.get("file_in")));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(conf.get("file_out")));
        return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        //...
        //managing input arguments
        //...

        CommandLineParser parser = new BasicParser();
        HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
        try {
            cmd = parser.parse(options, args);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            formatter.printHelp("usage:", options);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        Integer k = Integer.parseInt(cmd.getOptionValue("k"));
        Integer m = Integer.parseInt(cmd.getOptionValue("m"));
        String file_in_string = cmd.getOptionValue("file_in");
        String file_out_string = cmd.getOptionValue("file_out");
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set("file_in", file_in_string);
        conf.set("file_out", file_out_string);
        util = new Utility(k, m);
        int res = ToolRunner.run(conf, new HadoopRun(), args);

        System.exit(res);
    }

}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with your combiner. Reducer will have all the data of the same key.  Post your code and see why your reducer doesn't work as expected.

Comment: I posted the code (the x-string are actually called k-mer), the aggregated strings as value at point 4 are called superkmer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a method that counts the occourrences of any substring of length x

```java
    /**
     * 
     * @param s string to get substrings from 
     * @param x length of substring you want
     * @return hashmap with each substring being the keys and amount of occurrences being the values 
     */
    public static HashMap countSub(String s,int x){
        HashMap<String,Integer> hm = new HashMap();
        int to = s.length()-x+1;
        hm.put(s.substring(0,x),1);


        for(int i=1;i<to;i++){
            x++;
            String next = s.substring(i,x);
            boolean b = false;

            for (String key : hm.keySet()) {
                b = key.equals(next);
                //if key already exists increment value
                if(b) {
                    hm.put(key,hm.get(key)+1);
                    break;
                }
            }
            //else make new key
            if(!b) hm.put(next,1);
        }
        return hm;
    }
```

The method returns a hash map which seems kinda like the format you had in your question, where each key is a substring and each value is the number of occurrences of that substring.

Comment: thanks, but its an academic project on hadoop, the datasets are 32+ GB. A sequential code like this won't work for memory and computation time both. I have to implement that algorithm in hadoop.